# How to use ctype_alpha with UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

How to use ctype_alpha with UTF-8?

I have this code:

```
if(empty($_POST) === false) {      
    if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty ($_POST['first_name'])){
        if (ctype_alpha($_POST['first_name']) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Please enter your First Name with only letters!';
        }   
    }
}
```

Here I check if everything is fine. If not I get an error.

But if I use letters like ščćž - UTF-8 then I also get errors. So how I can solve this problem? I need for first names to have letters only but UTF-8 characters like ščćž must be allowed.

Comment: BTW, `isset && !empty` is redundant. Use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use regex for latin characters, change this condition:

```
if (ctype_alpha($_POST['first_name']) === false)
```

to:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}]+$/u', $_POST['first_name'])
```

Or - to allow whitespace:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}\s]+$/u', $_POST['first_name'])
```

Comment: I write: 
    if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty ($_POST['first_name'])){
     if (preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}]+$/u', $_POST['first_name'])) {
     $errors[] = 'Please enter your First Name with only letters!'.$_POST['first_name'];
     } 
    } but again I get my error!!!

Comment: Oops, sorry, should be "if not preg_match" - with `!` - I edited my answer.