# phalcon validation cirillic utf8

Tags: validation, utf-8, phalcon

I try validation Alnum in my Phalcon model. But I get not the correct validation when I enter symbols in Cyrillic (utf8)

```
$validation->add(
    'title',
    new \Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Alnum([
        "message" => 'Поле Город содержит недопустимые символы',
    ])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon's validation service is using the PHP built in `ctype_alnum` function (**[as seen here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/validation/validator/alnum.zep)**), which does not support multibyte strings.

Quick snippets for testing:

```
$validation = new \Phalcon\Validation(); 
$validation->add(
    'name',
    new \Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Alnum(
        [
            'message' => 'Validation failed',
        ]
    )
);
$words = [
    'test1234',
    't__est1234',
    'тест123',
]; 
echo '<h2>Phalcon Validation</h2>';
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $messages = $validation->validate(['name' => $word]);
    if (count($messages)) {
        echo '[N] '. $word, '<br>';
    } else {
        echo '[Y] '. $word, '<br>';
    }
}

echo '<h2>PHP `ctype_alnum`</h2>';
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (ctype_alnum($word)) {
        echo '[Y] '. $word, '<br>';
    } else {
        echo '[N] '. $word, '<br>';
    }
}
```

**Results:**

```
Phalcon Validation
[Y] test1234
[N] t__est1234
[N] тест123


PHP `ctype_alnum`
[Y] test1234
[N] t__est1234
[N] тест123
```

I'm afraid you have to use `preg_match` to solve your problem. Quick sample:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s\-]+$/u", $string);
```

Source: [Using Arabic characters with ctype_alnum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153002/using-arabic-characters-with-ctype-alnum) or [How to use ctype_alpha with UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237987/how-to-use-ctype-alpha-with-utf-8)

And finally, here is info on how to create your own validator: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/validation#validators

**Update: @Vladimir Kompaniec solution from comments!**

```
$validator->add('city', new Callback([ 
    'callback' => function () { 
        if (empty($this->subway)) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return (0 != preg_match("/[\w\d\s\-А-Яа-я]+/u", $this->subway)); 
    }, 
    'message' => 'Поле метро содержит недопустимые символы', 
    'cancelOnFail' => true, 
]));
```

Comment: In my model's method validate i add to validator callback function :

    $validator->add(
                'city',
                new Callback([
                    'callback' => function () {
                        if (empty($this->subway))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
    
                        return (0 != preg_match("/[\w\d\s\-А-Яа-я]+/u", $this->subway));
                    },
                    'message' => 'Поле метро содержит недопустимые символы',
         'cancelOnFail' => true, ]));

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to add your solution to help others in future :)